# Camry 1994 antenna doesn't go down all the way

Tags: toyota, audio, camry

It is Camry LE 1994. The motorized antenna doesn't go down all the way when I turn off the engine. How can I replace it?

Comment: Is it mounted in the front or rear fender?

Comment: It is mounted in the read fender.

Comment: you may wish to try lubricating the antenna first if you have not already. Various sources recommend either powdered graphite, silicone spray, or paste wax. Avoid anything "wet" like a traditional oil as it can attract dust and gum up the works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my first car, similar to yours.

The motorized antenna has little plastic teeth that allow it to move up and down and the plastic teeth near the top was worn down so it would always stick up a couple inches.

Sounds like a similar issue so you might want to check that. I had to replace the antenna and if I recall it wasn't too expensive.

Comment: I don't believe this really answers the question of "how".

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to.Extend fully and remove any corrosion/gunk.Apply a little penetrine
and you may resolve the problem.With constant use the server motor can have worn components